# WebScraping issues in python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from [this website called Anhembi](http://www.anhembi.com.br/agenda/)

But when I try all the options from selenium to find elements, I get nothing. Anyone know why this happens?

I've already tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="agenda_result_laco_box"]')
```

And made a `for-loop` through that to click in every single one and get the info I need which consists of the day, website and name of the events. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you give us manual steps after URL is opened?

Comment: Can u give a an example?

Comment: x = driver.find_element_by_name('month')
 print(range(len(x)))

Comment: What is your goal after web site is opened?

Comment: and range len of this thing returns [0,0]

Comment: get all data from the part where's bellow  "VOCE BUSCOU: JULHO DE 2018"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, there is an **iframe** involved , you need to switch the focus of your web driver in order to interact with elements which are in `iframe/frameset/frame`.

You can try with this **code** :

```
driver.get("http://www.anhembi.com.br/agenda/") 

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[src='http://intranet.spturis.com.br/intranet/modulos/booking/anhembisite_busca.php']"))
all_data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.agenda_result_laco_box")

print(len(all_data))

for data in all_data:
  print(data.text)
```

Comment: can u explain me whats's an iframe, please?

Comment: iframe is basically , used to embed another document within the current HTML document. For more you can refer this : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: and how could i get all info of the + simbol too?

Comment: Didn't get you. all the info means ? With the above code you will get everything that is under `Você buscou: JULHO DE 2018` and I don't know what +simbol is ?

Comment: If you are talking about the + sign which is just preceded by date , then you will have to click on each + sign one by one and scrape the data.